# Getting image that is one level up from current directory

Tags: filepath

I have a folder structure set up like this.

```
 Slide
    |_views
        |_pictures
              |_lakeDay
                  |_picture1.jpg
        |_landing
             |_picture.ejs
```

Here is my problem. I am currently working on `picture.ejs` and I want to use the `<img>` tag to incluse `picture1.jpg` but I am confused on what the filepath would be. I tried the following:

```
../pictures/lakeDay/picture1.jpg
```

That didn't work. Any leads?

Comment: The underscores in the names of your files/folders are just here to show the tree level ?
If not, you forgot it in your path.

Comment: They are just to show tree levels

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a question of rights.
If you work on Linux with Apache, you can try to give the rights of the apache group to your project:

```
chown -R www-data Slide/
```